# list author's posts in author.php

Tags: author

I want to list 10 last posts of author in author.php template.
I used this code:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

But I can see only the last post of current author. Any help?

Comment: Before that `while`, there's some `QUERY`... that's the important part. Please, edit your Question and add this information to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply add:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1' );
```

just before your code so you get :

```
<?php
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1' );
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: =o `query_posts` !

Comment: @TomJNowell I know and that's way i started my answer with the _easiest way_ ! The preferred way is hooking into `pre_get_posts`

Comment: Fair dos, your answer does work afterall =]

Answer (score 3):

Rather than clutter your author template, invoke a second query, and use `query_posts` ( avoid `query_posts` ), instead use this filter on `pre_get_posts` instead:

```
function wpse_show_all_authors($query){
    // if it's an author query
    if($query->is_author()){
        // put all the posts on page 1
        $query->set('posts_per_page',-1);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse_show_all_authors');
```

Put it in functions.php and it will work its magic on any and all author templates you have, without needing to modify author.php or execute 2 DB queries instead of 1.

Comment: Side note: this will add a check on every page load. not like the `query_post` method which will only effect author archives.

Comment: I consider an if statement opcode to be orders of magnitude faster than a second DB query and thus worth the cost of a handful of instructions for a simple value comparison, a cost that can be eliminated trivially in even the most elegant of codebases, and that's done by WP Core itself many, many times already.