# Archives and category of authors

Tags: categories, sidebar, archives, author

Description of the problem:

I should make a blog with, let's say 4 authors (may be more).
The blog shoud have a page 'blog-page-1' (without sidebar) on which will be the last post of each author and a page 'blog-page-2' (with sidebar) on which will be diplayed only posts of a specific author, depends on which post user clicked on 'blog-page-1'.
Also blog sidebar should have recent-posts, archives and categories of that author, clicking on which will display 'blog-page-2' with the specific content.

Any ideas how to make archives and category of specific author?

Page 'blog-page-1' I will do as is written [here (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-post-to-show-one-post-per-author)](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-post-to-show-one-post-per-author).

Also I found for author posts display [this (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71127/list-authors-posts-in-author-php)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71127/list-authors-posts-in-author-php)

Comment: Questions are solved here by accepting an answer, not by adding a word to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I made a part of it, and I think I should post it here :)
This is a part of index.php. It show a post per each author by default, or if a post is selected it shows the post centent and 2 post before it.

```
        if(!is_single()) {
            //get all users, iterate through users, query for one post for the user,
            //if there is a post then display the post title, author, content info
            $blogusers = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=author');
            //print_r($blogusers);
            //die();
            if ($blogusers) {
                foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
                    $args = array(
                        'author' => $bloguser->ID,
                        'showposts' => 1
                    );
                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    //print_r($my_query);
                    //die();
                    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        // $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
                        // echo 'This is one post for author with User ID: ' . $user->ID . ' ' . $user->user_firstname . ' ' . $user->user_lastname;
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                            get_template_part('content');
                        endwhile;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(have_posts()) {
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part('content');
                    $author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
                    $datetime = get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                endwhile;

                wp_reset_postdata();

                //echo $datetime;

                $args = array(
                    'author' => $author_ID,
                    'showposts' => 2
                );

                function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
                    global $datetime;
                    // posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010
                    $where .= " AND post_date < '" . $datetime . "'";
                    return $where;
                }

                add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    // $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
                    // echo 'This is one post for author with User ID: ' . $user->ID . ' ' . $user->user_firstname . ' ' . $user->user_lastname;
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                        $more = 0;
                        get_template_part('content', 'special');
                    endwhile;
                }
            }
        }
```

About categories, I made one parent category for each author, and show its subcategories.

```
    global $wp_query;
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    //print_r($wp_query->post);

    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = isset($categories[0]) ? $categories[0] : 0;
    foreach($categories as $c) {
        if($c->parent == 0) $category = $c;
    }

    //print_r($category);

    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $category->cat_ID,
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'pad_counts' => true
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    print_r($categories);
```

For author archives, I customized the wordpress function `wp_get_archives()` like so:

```
    /* Replace old $defaults */
    $defaults = array(
        'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => '',
        'format' => 'html', 'before' => '',
        'after' => '', 'show_post_count' => false,
        'echo' => 1, 'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_author' => '',
    );

    /* ... */

    /* And the $where filter */
    $where = apply_filters( 'getarchives_where', "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'" . ($post_author != '' ? ' AND post_author = ' . $post_author : ''), $r );
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but I use this.

And at the end, recent post of the current author

```
    /* Get posts related to curent post author */
    function get_related_author_posts($number = 5) {
        global $authordata, $post;

        $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => $number ) );
        $output = '<ul>';

        foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
            $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';

        return $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make specific pages (like landing pages) and call a specific header (or footer) template (i.e. *header-authorPaul.php*) by calling `get_header ( "authorPaul" );`
and then verifying that the author has post(s).
Show the last one(s) if any.
The same goes for archives.

Comment: Okay. I will think at it. Now I think to use parent categories for each user. About archives I don't know at moment.

Comment: Question: how do I make url of author archive?